# How do I get the "Sniper Duel" achievement in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, achievements

[image: Screenshot of achievement interface]

The "Sniper Duel" achievement in Minecraft requires me to kill a skeleton from 50 meters away. Is this equivalent to 50 blocks? What is the easiest way to do this? I've recently located a skeleton spawner near my base, how can I use this to my advantage?

Comment: `meters == blocks` And spawners are only active if you are within 16 blocks of them, so it would be tricky, but possibly you can make it spawn some, then run far far away.

Comment: Completely unrelated, but what texture pack are you using? Looks cool.

Comment: @MrSmooth: It's [Tronic](http://evilmousestudios.com/tronic/).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since you have a skeleton spawner, that should make it easier. What I would do is build a wall/fence around it so that skeletons are contained, and leave some holes for you to shoot through. Next, if looking through the holes does not activate the monster spawner, I would have a doorway that leads inside the spawner room to activate it, then run out. The building will ensure that the skeletons do not wander off.

To kill the skeleton, first hit it with a sword through the hole until it's one hit away from death. Then, back off 50 blocks and snipe it!

Comment: @fredley the point of hitting it with a sword was to get its attention, and not to nearly kill it.

Comment: What do you mean by 'get its attention'? It is hostile to you by default.

Comment: oops, looks like I forgot that.

Comment: So @Brant did it work?

Comment: FWIW, I just used roughly this strategy and it worked. I had an already tamed skeleton spawner XP farm, so I made a hole to aim through in the drop area, dug a tunnel 52 blocks away (just to make sure), and shot a skeleton. I had to make the tunnel 4 blocks tall to allow for the arrows' arc, and fire many times since bows are notably inaccurate at that distance.

Answer (score 5):

I think it also counts if you're 50 blocks above the skeleton. Build a snipers tower, wait until dark and then snipe away!

Comment: Or, even better, a skeleton pit.

Answer (score 5):

Just sitting on a 50 meter tall tower and sniping does not trigger the achievement. You need to be in a "duel", i.e. within the skeleton's vision range to "get its attention" as mentioned above. Then you can back off (up) to 50 meters and complete the duel.

Answer (score 4):

There is another way. Build a tower around the skeleton so he can't escape. Then, count your blocks and by the building, put down 50 blocks like a bridge and go close to the skeleton. Shoot 3 powerful shots and go to the end of the bridge. Make sure that your tower looks like a wishing well with no doors, all walls and 1 window without glass pointing towards to bridge. Now, fire as best as you can until you hit him. Then he will die and you earn the achievement.

NOTE: if you have 50 blocks stand on the edge right before you fall or make it 51 blocks.

It worked for me, so it is achievable.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is spawn a skeleton in a little house with a roof, hit him twice with a diamond sword, back up 50 blocks, then aim up and fire. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

50 block sides (squares) = 50 meters in Minecraft. Try shooting the skeleton on a horizontal axis. Try going to the limit of where you can still see the skeleton. Then, raise your bow and fire! If you don't hit it, try again until it's done.

Answer (score -2):

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Achievements

> Sniper Duel is unachievable under any circumstances.

My own experimentation corroborates with the above.  I believe Squeaky and Joe the Person were speculating.

I tested from a tower on survival single player (SSP) hard mode.
I tested from well over 50 meters on SSP hard.
I tested from well over 50 meters on survival multiplayer hard mode.

After multiple confirmed kills that measured as more than 50 meters, I still haven't got the achievement.

Other corroborations:
http://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/m0wx3/sniper_duel_achievement/

That said, my experiments were all done prior to 1.0.0's release.

Comment: Make sure you have the prerequisite achievements.

Comment: I tried it too. I succeded by hitting it orizontally,not vertically.

Comment: Other comments above make it sound like you have to "get the skeletons attention" first - go close and hit it to make it follow/attack you.